# Error connecting to Sharepoint site from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am receiving the below error when I try to connect to the Sharepoint site using python.
I checked the "Enable Security Defaults" setting on our Azure AD tenant and it is set to NO.
We are connecting using our personal account which has MFA enabled.

Can someone please help to understand what we are missing here?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjHUl.png):

> `AuthError: Authentication Failure: AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access ''.`

Comment: Did searching for the error or error code not help at all, then?

Comment: Hello @RandomDavis, I did a search and a couple of them referred to changing the security setting in AAD which we already have set to NO